# Angularjs display data from array in a table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to display data from array in a table.

This is what I have:

controllers.js:

```
app.controller('DriverController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {

        //Defining the $http service for getting the sources
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/Driver/GetDrivers'
        }).
        success(function (data) {
            $scope.drivers = data;
        });
    }]);
```

Data I'm getting:

[image]

HTML Markup:

```
<table ng-controller="DriverController">
                    <thead>
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody ng-repeat="driver in Drivers">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                {{driver.FirstName}}
                            </td>

                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

End result:

[image]

### Update

I tried this as well, just to see if angular is hooked up correctly:

```
app.controller('DriverController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {

        //Defining the $http service for getting the sources
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/Driver/GetDrivers'
        }).
        success(function (data) {
            $scope.Drivers = data;
            $scope.Test = "testt";
            console.log('data retrieved');
            console.log($scope.Drivers);
        });

    }]);
```

And I updated the view:

```
@using ui.ViewModels
@model DriversViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Drivers List";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div data-ng-app="app">
        <section class="panel">
            <header class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-actions">
                    <a href="#" class="panel-action panel-action-toggle" data-panel-toggle></a>
                    <a href="#" class="panel-action panel-action-dismiss" data-panel-dismiss></a>
                </div>

                <h2 class="panel-title">Drivers List</h2>
            </header>
            <div class="panel-body" data-ng-controller="DriverController">
                <p>{{Test}}</p>
                <table class="table table-no-more table-bordered table-striped mb-none">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">First Name</th>
                            <th class="text-right hidden-xs hidden-sm">Middle Name</th>
                            <th class="text-right">Last Name</th>
                            <th class="text-right">Party</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var p in Model.Drivers)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td data-title="Code">@p.Id</td>
                                <td data-title="Company" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">@p.FirstName</td>
                                <td data-title="Change" class="text-right hidden-xs hidden-sm">@p.MiddleName</td>
                                <td data-title="Price" class="text-right">@p.LastName</td>
                                <td data-title="Change %" class="text-right">@p.Party.Name</td>
                            </tr>

                        }

                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <table>
                    <thead>
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="driver in drivers">
                            <td>{{driver.firstName}}</td>
                            <td>{{driver.lastName}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </section>
    </div>

}
```

I tried a simple thing too, such as  `<p>{{driver.Test}}</p>` but as you can see no value is shown.

So I think there is some disconnection between angular and the mvc app, what do you think I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding ng-repeat on tr tags not on tbody tag.

Edit: 
maybe you forgot to place ng-app outside of your table, this fiddle works

https://jsfiddle.net/xy2y1b9y/

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <script>
        angular.module('app', [])
            .controller('DriverController', function($scope) {
            $scope.Drivers = [{
                FirstName: "first"
            }, {
                FirstName: 'second'
            }]
        })
    </script>
    <table ng-controller="DriverController">
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-repeat="driver in Drivers">
            <tr>
                <td>{{driver.FirstName}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

(although placement of ng-repeat should be on tr tags)

Comment: still the same @kodvin

Comment: updated my question with some more data pls check thx @kodvin

Comment: ok @kodvin thanks for your help, with your $scope.Drivers value I'm able to display them in the view. but I'm not sure what is wrong with the json array I'm sending to the view and why is not displayed correctly.

Comment: this is how its shown in firebug https://i.gyazo.com/45bc004672cc8f1edb8bbfe2cf5ccbbc.png

Comment: Maybe you are assigning to $scope.Drivers an object with property Drivers that is an array? $scope.Drivers = {Drivers: [youData]}?

Comment: How can I modify that? I think that's the problem @kodvin

Comment: You should console.log(data) and if it is an object with property Drivers, assign $scope.Drivers = data.Drivers not $scope.Drivers = data. Just check if the assigned $scope.Drivers is an array that you want to iterate(maybe data has property "status" and "results" and "results" has "Drivers").

Answer (score 0):

Put the ng-repeat inside the tables tr:

```
<table ng-controller="DriverController">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="driver in drivers">
            <td>{{driver.firstName}}</td>
            <td>{{driver.lastName}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```